# error 404 php but the file is in public_html folder

Tags: php

I upload my simple website using 000webhost free service. I've checked and linked index.php to every page in my website.

```
<ul>
    <li class="selected">
        <a href="public_html/index.php">home</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="public_html/about.php">about</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="public_html/gallery.php">gallery</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="public_html/history.php">history</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="public_html/contact.php">contact</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

but when I access it in my website, it shows error 404.

thanks before.

Comment: Have you tried uploading a simple `index.html` file to your public_html folder?

Comment: Not Found

The requested URL /public_html/about.php was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Comment: That is because you are linking it wrong.   remove the `public_html/` from your link., and just link to `about.php` as is

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't reference `public_html` in your links;  that's designed for the back end.

For instance, this:

```
        <li class="selected">
            <a href="public_html/index.php">home</a>
        </li>
```

Should just be

```
        <li class="selected">
            <a href="index.php">home</a>
        </li>
```

Your main page should be stored as `index.html`  (or `index.php`) in your `public_html` directory.

Comment: Honestly, I can't believe I didn't notice that xD

Comment: If it solved your problem, click the "check" as solved.  Thanks!